# how to install that Nvidia 331.45 version.... Nvidia newly released Nvidia 331.45 version updated drive.. now in my pc Nvidia 319 Updated drive

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-current-dev

i'am a windows user. recently i now am switched in Ubuntu 13.10.. it's is every thing new for me... commanding and setting whatever it is every thing new for me.. and now my Pc monitor resolution is not set. i have a Nvidia Graphics card.. Soo it's is compalsary set that resolution setting how i don;t know how to set that settings.... i'am also updated Ubuntu 13.10 current graphic drive setting... but in Nvidia newly released Nvidia 331.45 version updated drive.. now in my pc Nvidia 319 Updated drive .. how to install that Nvidia 331.45 version

Comment: go to system settings, and choose Displays. There you can change the resolution.

Comment: Please consider to [edit] your question in a way that we can see what is more important for you (1) a guide on how to set screen resolution, or (2) a guide on how to install bleeding edge untested and likely unstable proprietary drivers ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Open source drivers you can change your desktop resolution from `Displays` app search it in your dash<-- dash is the search thing you have.

If you want to install newest nvidia drivers You should use [ppa](http://digitalstudio7.blogspot.com/2013/10/ubuntu-abc-lesson-301265-what-is-ppa.html)

If you want to use the latest and greatest versions of nvidia drivers you should use this ppa
[“xorg crack pushers” team](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa)
But I must worn you that this drivers are after beta versions so think twice before updating you might better of sticking to the version you can install from your additional drivers menu.
Personally I have been using it for quite some time and no problem with that ppa.

There are many ways to install this but I did it like so

First add ppa to your source list

Open terminal and type this in it and press enter

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

after it is finished type

```
sudo apt-get update
```

now open software & updates app
 select additional drivers and you will see new nvidia driver version 
[image]
select it and press apply changes 
ignore that in the end it is written (open source) it is not open source drivers they are proprietary. 
after it will finish installing drivers reboot your pc and you will be using your new drivers. 
now you have your nvidia control panel in your dash and can change settings from it 
[image]

Do not worry about the updates it will automatically download the latest nvidia drivers from now on

one more thing welcome to fantastic Linux/Ubuntu community hope you will enjoy the ride